# In Vue, which has a higher priority, manually changing the DOM content or updating the DOM content through virtual DOM?

Tags: vue.js, event-loop

I've been studying Vue's nextTick recently, I wrote myself the following demo code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const vue = new Vue({
      el: '#root',
      template: '<div><div id="dom">{{msg}}</div><button @click="add">add</button></div>',
      data() {
        return {
          msg: 1
        }
      },
      watch: {
        msg(value) {
          console.log('msg>>>>>', value);
        }
      },
      methods: {
        add() {
          const dom = document.getElementById('dom');
          dom.textContent = '30'
          for(let i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
            this.msg ++
          }
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            console.log('msg.content2>>>>>>', dom.textContent)
          })
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

liveDemo:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwypjvxr/)

the result really confused me.
As i expected, after click the add button, `dom.textContent = '30'` change dom element's textConent to 30. and the next for loop, add `msg` to 4, as Vue will update page asynchronously, we cant see the newest result in the page. after `this.$nextTick`, Vue will use the updated `msg` to reRender the dom element immediately, which we know is 4 now. so the dom element's textContent should be 4 now, but it remains 30. why did this happen? where did i get wrong ?

Comment: "where did i get wrong ?" - by accessing dom directly. Likely Vue is unaware that you messed it up, so it wasn't properly updated.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks, I just don't know where I went wrong with my previous idea, and want to figure out what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out what's going on here:

When `dom.textContent = '30'` is executed, it changes the element's text content to '30'.

But it's not like what I thought before, which directly modifies the textContent of the `dom` element's Text child node to the new content. Instead, it generates a new `Text` child node and replaces the original one.

Later, in the `$nextTick` function, Vue uses the newest `msg` value, which is now 4, to update the `Text` node's content. However, the `Text` node Vue is using now is the one that stored in the `el` property, which is the old one, not the updated dom element's `Text` child node. As a result, this change is useless, and both the page and the console.log statement fail to show the expected result.

After change the demo code into the following version, I finally get what I want:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const vue = new Vue({
      el: '#root',
      template: '<div><div id="dom">{{msg}}</div><button @click="add">add</button></div>',
      data() {
        return {
          msg: 1
        }
      },
      watch: {
        msg(value) {
          console.log('msg>>>>>', value);
        }
      },
      methods: {
        add() {
          const dom = document.getElementById('dom');
          dom.childNodes[0].textContent = '30'; //change dom's child node's textContent, not dom's own textContent; 
          for(let i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
            this.msg ++
          }
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            console.log('msg.content2>>>>>>', dom.textContent)
          })
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

[live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8mpy6f9x/)

another demo:
[change div's textContent creates a new Text node](https://jsfiddle.net/48q7puwb/)